# I need a formula that would check the order inside the cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sequence, equation

I have an Excel sheet, there are 500 cells with only data in column E. How do I check the cell does not have any numbers in a sequential order like 12345 or 54321 for example. Each cell has a 5 digit long number.

Comment: in vba, find the length of the cell and then in a loop check each character to see if it is 1 less than the previous.  repeat the loop for 1 greater than.  If either loop holds true you know you have a sequence of 1 greater or one less.  I hope you only have to check for that kind of sequence.  Gets a little more complex if you are looking for every odd or even number.

Comment: It doesn't get that much more complex for odds or evens. You would just have to repeat for 2 less and 2 greater.

Comment: or prime sequence, double sequence etc.  lots of potential sequences to check for.  Fibonacci?  They can all be checked for, the code just gets longer, thus more complex

Comment: Just trying to confirm I understand what he's talking about, - @pnuts

Comment: lol thanks that's good one- @pnuts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a formula:

```
=OR(AND(MID(A4,{1,2,3,4},1)+0=MID(A4,{2,3,4,5},1)-1),AND(MID(A4,{1,2,3,4},1)+0=MID(A4,{2,3,4,5},1)+1))
```

It checks the first four digits one-at-a-time against the last four digits, to see if all are either one more, or one less. That's where the +1 and -1 parts come in. The +0 parts just force the strings yielded by the `MID` function to be numbers.

It uses arrays but doesn't need to be array-entered.

[image]

Comment: The formula does need to add the Boolean value at the end to let the user know if it is sequential or not. Other than that, the formula code looked brilliant!

Comment: Thanks. I don't understand the comment about adding the boolean value at the end. The formula is boolean. Your question is very brief and not that clear, but interesting!

Comment: Oh, there is the error on the formula. Have you test the formula yet?

Comment: Yes I used it. The picture in the post shows the results.

Comment: Here's an screenshot link to [Excel](http://i.imgur.com/06OJqyb.png) P.S. Perhaps you haven't update the formula.

Comment: You are right, I haven't updated the formula. It looks like you've got the number 1 in column A and have it formatted as "00000" but that's just a guess. Remember, I am not a mind reader.

Comment: Gosh Doug! You are absolutely right! What is the right thing to do for the number 1 in column A?

Comment: What if the cell conains 21? Does that count as a sequential number, or are you only calling it sequential if it's five digits long?

Comment: I am only calling the sequential number if the cell has the sequence that is three digits long within the five digits.  For instance, 45601 is sequential because it had 456.

Comment: Ok, I officially give up on this one. You waited 12 days to mention this detail? Good luck!

Comment: Please tell me what is the hurry. I am not going anywhere, Doug. I really do need your help figuring out the right formula.

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF(AND(ABS(MID($B1,1,1)-MID($B1,2,1))=1,MID($B1,1,1)<MID($B1,2,1)),1,0)+IF(AND(ABS(MID($B1,2,1)-MID($B1,3,1))=1,MID($B1,2,1)<MID($B1,3,1)),1,0)+IF(AND(ABS(MID($B1,3,1)-MID($B1,4,1))=1,MID($B1,3,1)<MID($B1,4,1)),1,0)+IF(AND(ABS(MID($B1,4,1)-MID($B1,5,1))=1,MID($B1,4,1)<MID($B1,5,1)),1,0)
```

( A late option )

Comment: I don't understand why the B1 cell would be involved with A1 as the formula code suggested.

Comment: @User3299153 : When testing my formulas I had put random 5-digits numbers in Column B. I should have changed cell references to A.Please disregard my formula, as an answer was given by Glancy before I refined it to account for shorter sequences and prior edits of your original post.